# Combining Synchronous Python w/ NodeJS

Tags: python, node.js, asynchronous, process, promise

I have a node script that looks like this:

```
// Preset Modules...
const fs = require("fs-extra");
const path = require("path");
const { join } = path;
const axios = require("axios");

// Global/Multi modules...
const { today } = require("./keys/globals");
const { logger } = require("./logger");

// Sequence modules...
const downloader = require("./downloader");
const settingScraper = require("./settings");
const treeMaker = require("./treeMaker");
/****/ const pythonWriter = require("./pythonWriter"); /****/
const fbDaemon = require("./firebase");
const zipper = require("./zipper");
const mailer = require("./mailer");
const { success, failure } = require("./results");

logger.write(`\nStarting download for: ${today}, at ${Date.now()}`);

axios.get(`http://federalregister.gov/api/v1/public-inspection-documents.json?conditions%5Bavailable_on%5D=${today}`)
  .then(downloader)
  .then(settingScraper)
  .then(treeMaker)
/****/  .then(pythonWriter) /****/
  .then(fbDaemon) // Should pass down array structure, like in config file.
  .then(zipper)
  .then(mailer)
  .then(success)
  .catch(failure);
```

The function downloads a number of files from an API online, and the pythonWriter is a separate module. Within that module I would like to trigger a python script, which would "pause" or execute synchronously, before they pythonWriter returned a promise. The promise wouldn't have to contain any data.

Look something like this:

```
const util = require("util");
const spawn = require("child_process").spawn;

const pythonWriter = () => {
  const process = spawn("python", ["./script.py"]);
}

module.exports = pythonWriter;
```

How can I spawn or create a sub-process that executes synchronously before the rest of my Javascript code? Or, if that's not possible, return a promise-like object that would then trigger a separate then-block?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Have you looked at the child_process documentation?  You can either use `spawnSync()` or you can watch for events on the childProcess object returned by spawn to know when its done or you can use the callback function with `.exec()` or `.execFile()` to see when they are done.  It's not clear what you're asking that is fully covered in the child_process doc.

Comment: Thank you. This is what I needed, just looked into spawn a bit more and then on exit, performed the rest of the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at the [child_process documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html)?

You can either use [`spawnSync()`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawnsync_command_args_options) or you can watch for events on the childProcess object returned by spawn to know when its done or you can use the callback function with `.exec()` or `.execFile()` or `.spawn()` to see when they are done.

It seems that what you're asking is already covered in the child_process doc.

Here's an example using `.spawn()` taken from the doc:

```
const { spawn } = require('child_process');
const ls = spawn('ls', ['-lh', '/usr']);

ls.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
  console.log(`stdout: ${data}`);
});

ls.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
  console.log(`stderr: ${data}`);
});

ls.on('close', (code) => {
  console.log(`child process exited with code ${code}`);
});
```

You could listen for the `close` event to see when it's done.